# TYPO3 store Extension-Builder image via FormFields.html

Tags: typo3, backend

Images currently are not handled by the extension-builder.
I am looking for a kind of "f:form", where I can store the image file name with the submit function, inside FormFields.html.

If I use `f:form.textfield` I get in trouble with format.
I already tries 
    ...originalResource.url and
    ...originalResource.name

I am using TYPO3 7.6.14

How I have to handle this task?

Comment: You just want to add a field to enter the file name into or do you want a frontend upload for FAL? Do you use FAL at all or is it a classic file upload in the backend?

Comment: want to know, in which way I have to store image, if I have the filename.
For example: fileadmin/Test/...
For extbase it should be FAL, as I know

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a File Upload with FAL in Extbase is not that easy. Here is an example extension in Github - mostly I do it like there: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example

But be warned: It's not for beginners...

Comment: Thanks for yourexample extension.
So far I am understand, image is from the type  
@var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference.

Comment: Thanks for yourexample extension. So far I am understand, image is from the type @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference. 
Which FileReference function I can use to get a filereference from the $fileName?